# Angularjs dynamically expanding table with select

Tags: angularjs

I have data coming from third party system, that makes up a AngularJS select.
The data may build one or more select.

I can count the number of select (y) it can build select dynamically but select does behaves in weird way when I select options

```
<td ng-repeat="y in  numCols track by $index" ng-init="myText='ChoiceCAP'+$index;myText2='ChoiceFO'+$index">        
    <select ng-model="mydata[myText]" >             
    <option selected value="mydata[myText]" > {{mydata[myText]}} </option> <option value="mydata[myText2]" > {{mydata[myText2]}}</option>
    </select>
    </td>
```

Here is the data I receive: it can be one or more  of the ChoiceCAP and ChoiceFO and do not have preset number of values.

> {"ChoiceCAP0":"Jonny","ChoiceFO0":"Mini","ChoiceCAP1":"Mini","ChoiceFO1":"Jonny","ChoiceCAP2":"Jonny","ChoiceFO2":"Mini"}

Comment: Can you provide a working plunker for this? So that we can see the behaviour of `select`

Comment: *behaves in weird way* is a almost completely useless statement when asking for help. If you are more explicit, you can get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the model , Took care of it with a different scope variable that fixed the issue